# Is it possible to store a JavaScript function that returns a string in a php variable?

Tags: javascript, php

something like :

```php
<?php
   $phpVar = "<script> function jsFunc(){ return 'Hello world';} </script>";
?>
```

is that even possible? if no, is there a way to do same thing?

If Ajax is the only solution, how do I retrieve a value of an input and store it as a php variable?

I tried something like this and it doesn't work.

```html
<input type=text value="hello" id="myInput">
<?php    
    $phpVar = "<script> 
        function jsFunc(){ 
            var inputVal = $('#myInput').val();
            return inputVal;
        } 
        </script>";
?>
```

Comment: No! Remember javascript runs in the browser and PHP runs on the server. But you should lookup AJAX

Answer (score 0):

you can store this string in variable. for php interpreter it will be just a text string, nothing else. but when browser receives this data, string will be recognized as js function.

---

**UPDATE**

in this case easiest way for send data from browser to server is use a form. there is many [examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data) in the web how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

PHP runs at server side and JS in the browser (apart node and related technologies).
Only way you can do something similar would be do to render from PHP in your HTML a tag `<script> </script>` and add you JS function and executing it there.

Al thought I would definitely not suggest it.